Old movie about a man with healing powers who arrives in a town while looking for his mother
I'm looking for a movie from the 80's or 90's.
It's about a man with powers who is looking for his mother. He arrives in a town; there, he fixes a man's TV antenna and detects a kid's aneurysm. When he shakes hands with the kid's father, he can detect his gastric ulcer. At the end of the movie, a woman tells him about a bike accident she had when she was a kid, and how a woman healed her. He now knows his mother has the same powers he has.
He continues his search for his mother.

What language was in the movie? What country was it set in?

I remember seeing this movie on US TV back in the 80s or early 90s.  No clue as to the title.

I had a flash memory of John Rhys-Davies as the evil scientist dude and tracked it down.
The Gifted One was a 1989 American fantasy television film that aired on NBC on June 25, 1989. This was a pilot project that never went to series.
From Wikipedia:

A young boy has the capability to use his body energy to heal people,
and detect illnesses. After growing up he escapes from the scientists
studying him in order to learn about his past and discover how he came
to have this ability. While on the run, he detects an aneurysm in the
neck of a child and attempts to convince his skeptical parents to seek
medical attention for him.

From Amazon:

Twenty-five years ago a young woman gave birth to a baby boy and then
disappeared. Meanwhile, the boy has grown up to discover that he has
extraordinary powers. He embarks on a search to find his mother and to
discover why he is…The Gifted One.

It's on YouTube:



Antenna repair at the 58 minute mark.
